# Why does GCC stop working?

Tags: compiling, gcc, chrome-os, chrome-book

I've followed [this tutorial](http://thomasloughlin.com/compile-on-chrome-os/) which shows how you can enable the GCC compiler on ChromeOS, which uses the following commands below.

```
sudo /usr/share/vboot/bin/make_dev_ssd.sh --remove_rootfs_verification --partitions 2
sudo mount -i -o remount,exec /home/chronos/user/
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=~/Toolchain/usr/include/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/Toolchain/usr/lib:~/Toolchain/usr/lib/binutils/armv7a-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi/2.25.1/
export PATH=$PATH:~/Toolchain/usr/armv7a-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi/gcc-bin/4.9.3/:~/Toolchain/usr/armv7a-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi/binutils-bin/2.25.1/
sudo sed -i 's/\/usr/\/home\/chronos\/user\/Toolchain\/usr/g' ~/Toolchain/usr/lib/libc.so
```

Once executed, I'm able to compile source files right up until my shell instance terminates. Once I return to the shell later, all attempts at source compilation via `./configure` fail.

I suspected that the exported variables become lost after the instance is terminated. I try implementing the same commands exactly as before, but the ability to compile seems irrevocably lost.

The `config.log` stream presents the following error:

```
configure:3378: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3400: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
/home/chronos/user/Toolchain/usr/armv7a-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi/binutils-bin/2.25.1/ld: cannot find /home/chronos/user/Toolchain/home/chronos/user/Toolchain/home/chronos/user/Toolchain/home/chronos/user/Toolchain/home/chronos/user/Toolchain/home/chronos/user/Toolchain/home/chronos/user/Toolchain/usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:3404: $? = 1
configure:3442: result: no
```

Something really peculiar happens to the path...

```
cannot find /home/chronos/user/Toolchain/home/chronos/user/Toolchain/home/chronos/user/Toolchain/home/chronos/user/Toolchain/home/chronos/user/Toolchain/home/chronos/user/Toolchain/home/chronos/user/Toolchain/usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a
```

I feel that I've exhausted my limited knowledge of Linux to resolve this issue. Is anyone able to provide some insight as to what's going on?

Comment: I think, maybe I shouldn't keep replicating that `sed` command. It's the only instruction I don't get... Do I keep appending to the target path when I keep running it? I don't understand what the target is either. If I could figure it out, maybe it could be reset...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you repeatedly use `sed` in this way, you keep appending to the shared object file `~/Toolchain/usr/lib/libc.so`. So after the first run, this corrupts the file path.

If your path is corrupted, navigate to the file and manually change the contents of `libc.so` to the following:

```
/* GNU ld script
   Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
   the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-littlearm)

GROUP ( /lib/libc.so.6 /home/chronos/user/Toolchain/usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a  AS_NEEDED ( /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 ) )
```

Trouble is, when the shell has been closed, it's important that if you wish to keep compiling once you do return, you must re-run the `export` flags since these *do* get lost. You need to do this until you seek a more permanent solution which establishes the flags upon initialization of the shell, i.e. via `~/.bashrc`.